# copy records from one table in mysql to another using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Copy_Tab()
        Dim createSql1 As String
        con = New MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim tblname = TextBox3.Text & "_" & ComboBox1.Text
        createSql1 = "Select * from '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(createSql1, con)

        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim adapter1 As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter1.Fill(table)
        Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand("Insert into tblname ([Code], [PCID],[Assigned_To], [Deployed])values(@CD, @PD, @AT,@DP)", con)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@CD", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = table.Rows(0)(1)  'here (0) is the column no. and (1) is the cell no.
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PD", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = table.Rows(0)(2)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@AD", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = table.Rows(0)(3)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@DP", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = table.Rows(0)(4)

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Hi guys, go this code and receiving an error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Monitor'' at line 1'

here is what im doing. I'm creating and inventory check software where I need to create a new table everytime we do an inventory then i need to copy the current inventory list from my mysql database. can you help me please?

Comment: Don't put your table name in `'`. And you can do this in one query

`Insert into tblname (Code, PCID, Assigned_To, Deployed)
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from another_table`

Comment: INSERT INTO another_table_name (col_no_1,col_no_2,col_no_3,col_no_4,col_no_5)
SELECT col_no_1,col_no_2,col_no_3,col_no_4,col_no_5 FROM from_table_name. Note: column datatype should be same

Comment: you guys are awesome!